# How to connect to a SQL Database on an Android Kotlin app

Tags: android, sql, database, kotlin

I am building an Android application with Kotlin. I am not very familiar with Databases and Backend in general, I have only used AWS DynamoDB and S3. I want to try something else and learn SQL. I want to connect my app to a Cloud SQL DB like MySQL or PostreSQL. I can't use SQLite because I want the app to be served remotely and be accessible by all the users. I don't need a server, instead I would like to use a server-less structure where I make queries to the DB on function calls from inside my App. How would I do that? I read online about services like planetscale and raiway.app but I can't find a way to connect to my tables there. Are they perhaps web-only?

Comment: mysql and sql server have to be installed on the computer where run the app, or try file based sqlite that can also sql, but all other not file based sql rdms need installation and a service

Comment: I don't want to use SQLite because I want the DB to be on the cloud.

Comment: then you need to write a REST api which takes care of all remote sql queries, all databases are not allowed tp be contacted from the internet, because of the security.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a remote back-end you can use retrofit https://square.github.io/retrofit/ otherwise you can use room library https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room.

I understand that you aren't going to use a Server but in the case where you have to make queries locally, i.e. you have your database on your PC, you must use retrofit and for doing this you must make a small API that will send you JSON and you can process your queries easily with that. If not, you can use room to connect to sqlite, a small database that is default on android phones.

Some Links :

- https://square.github.io/retrofit/,
- https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room.

Comment: I don't want to use SQLite because I want my DB to be stored remotely and accessed via the internet similarly to how AWS Amplify works. I want every user to be able to access all the users data at any time on any device.

Comment: In this case use Retrofit but if you are null like me in backend, sql... you can also use firebase it's a cloud solution from google it's a document oriented DBMS personally I use it all the time it allows me not to type a backend

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSsa9OlQJms

Comment: I have used firebase before and I don't want to use it for this project because it's a document db and I need an SQL db.

Comment: in that case you can use Retrofit try to see this https://github.com/KadirKuruca/NewsApp-MVVM-Hilt-Room-Retrofit, if you are doing compose https://github.com/cksadhukhan/ComposeRetrofit, https://github.com/josh-Muleshi/ComposeRetrofitMVVMDemo